# How to embed image in elementary OS Loki Mail email compose?

Tags: pantheon-mail

Is it possible to embed image in elementary OS Mail while writing email? I didn't find any option to do it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, embedded images are not a feature of Pantheon Mail (formerly Geary). You can follow [the wishlist request in the bug tracker here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1543630) or [post a bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/30707007-unable-to-paste-image-to-email-body) to encourage a developer to write the feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will be perfect enough if it could happen.